Need help getting Icons from a website not favicons
so I'm currently making a small personal project of mine and I found some icons from a website that I really want, but I tried searching up tutorials for it, like grabbing favicons/favicon grabbers but it grabs the website logo. I have been trying for a while now and I'm just confused so any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the website I'm talking about (https://modrinth.com/mods)
I tried Tutorials from Stackoverflow and Favicon Grabbers but it only grabbed the website logo. I want the icons, for example example image
and IF its possible I would like to grab possibly every single icon from the website as i'm looking to use all of them.

Please bear in mind that graphic content may be subject to licences. Even if they are not clearly protected you can't just "grap" these. If you're really interested in these exact icons/images – just contact the owners. Maybe they tell you they are using an open source library or allow you to use these for your purposes. Don't just grab images from other sites. Just because it's possible doesn't mean it's legal. Worth mentioning: people get frequently sued for these copyright violations mainly because you can obviously easily track usage of images via something like google image search!

You could use a web scraping script to parse the page and get all the SVG elements in the website.
const svgElements = document.querySelectorAll('svg *');
Then save them in a .svg file. It'll be a task.
Off-topic, these icons might be available at https://icon-sets.iconify.design/ too.

Hey As Far As I know you have cant access all icons at once as there is some icons which are svg and embedded directly in html

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Run
document.querySelectorAll("svg").forEach(i=>console.log(i.parentNode));
in the Browser console of your website
Then browse the results

